# How to see logs of Dockerfile build when using custom AWS Lambda container image

Tags: aws-lambda

AWS Lambda supports container images rather than using the standard Amazon Linux (2) image, but I can't figure out where the logs from the Dockerfile build are stored.

I can find and see the logs for the invocation (within the lambda function) but not the 'setup' step preceding the invocation, i.e. the `serverless deploy` step. Adding `--verbose` did not provide the logs.

Without this, I have no visibility into the success or logs of my build step.

Can anyone suggest where to find them?

Comment: You build the images yourself, before pushing them to ECR for Lambda to pull. So look for logs in the place where you do the build.

Comment: @gshpychka I `sls package` and `sls deploy`, the [Docker] build itself is hidden from me, and I was under the impression it in fact takes place on AWS not locally. I have two generated folders, `node_modules` and `.serverless`, neither of which I see any log files in. The `Dockerfile` is present in the `.serverless/my-service.zip` archive, not any build output. So the question remains of where to find logs from the Dockerfile build

Comment: I am not sure whether serverless has this capability. You can build it outside of serverless first, I guess.

Comment: To be clear - are you sure you're using the container support correctly? Do you have an `ecr` section in your `serverless.yaml`? Because if your function is deployed as a zip file, then it's not deployed as a container image. Please share the relevant part of your yaml.

Comment: Spot on! We figured it out after trying to add an `image` section to the YAML and it said you can't have both `handler` and `image`: there were no logs as the Dockerfile wasn't actually being used, now it's set up the expected logs appear in the `sls package` output. Just seen your comment, thanks that would have been what I needed :)